# Set HSTS, HttpOnly, Secure for js, jsp, css cookies?

Tags: javascript, apache, cookies, httponly

Do I have to implement HTTP Strict Transport Security, HttpOnly and Secure flag for all cookies found in the js, jsp, css web response resources?

All those security mechanisms are enabled for other web resources (HTML) but on a recent test, a Web security tool (Burp) is flagging js, jsp, css with missing those flags.

Is the best practice to enable HTTP Strict Transport Security, HttpOnly and Secure flags for cookies found in all web server response resources including js, jsp, css?

Comment: you are right those flags are for cookies; I edit my question; hope is more clear now. I was referring to the cookie flags found in the js, jsp, css server response

Comment: yes, Apache Tomcat. I didn't include server details to have a more general question